# Multiple fields to the same DB column

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

We are trying to speed up our app with [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). It can follow the `GenericForeignKey` relations, and it can go deeper with `__` but unfortunately it will fail if related model do not have such field.

Here is some example of model structure

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    event_object = models.ForeignKey(SomeModelA)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(SomeModelB)

class ModelC(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
```

So `ModelC` instance can point either to `ModelA` or `ModelB`. And I can use such queryset to prefetch both A and B models: `ModelC.objects.all().prefetch_related('content_object')` Unfortunately I also need to select the event object (`SomeModelA` or `SomeModelB`)

If I try to run

```
ModelC.objects.all().prefetch_related('content_object', 'content_object__event_object')
```

It will work if I have only `ModelC` instances that points to `ModelA`, but in ohter case it will fail because `ModelB` do not have the `event_object` field and have `event` instead.

This models are used in many places across the code so it's not a good idea to rename the field. So I wonder if there is a way to create an alias for a field/column.

I was trying to do like this:

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(SomeModelB)
    event_object = models.ForeignKey(SomeModelB, db_column='event_id', related_name='+')
```

to make two fields that point to the same column in DB table. However this is not working as it breaks the `save` method. Django creates an `UPDATE` SQL query where one column is placed twice and gets a DatabaseError

Is there any way to create such alias? Or maybe there is another solution to make `prefetch_related` not to throw an exception?

**Update**: In `save` method there is an `update_fields` parameter that can be used to exclude this field. However it was introduced in 1.5 and we are using 1.4. So I continue to search for an answer.

**Update #2**: @shx2 asked me to provide a traceback. There are 2 possible traceback. 
1st - when attribute is missing on the first object:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/igor/workspace/projectname/eggs/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 72, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/home/igor/workspace/projectname/eggs/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 97, in __iter__
    len(self)
  File "/home/igor/workspace/projectname/eggs/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 89, in __len__
    self._prefetch_related_objects()
  File "/home/igor/workspace/projectname/eggs/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 570, in _prefetch_related_objects
    prefetch_related_objects(self._result_cache, self._prefetch_related_lookups)
  File "/home/igor/workspace/projectname/eggs/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 1664, in prefetch_related_objects
    (attr, first_obj.__class__.__name__, lookup))
AttributeError: Cannot find 'event_object' on ModelB object, 'content_object__event_object' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()
```

And if prefetch_related parameters are valid for the first object then I get the 2nd traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/igor/workspace/projectname/eggs/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 72, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/home/igor/workspace/projectname/eggs/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 97, in __iter__
    len(self)
  File "/home/igor/workspace/projectname/eggs/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 89, in __len__
    self._prefetch_related_objects()
  File "/home/igor/workspace/projectname/eggs/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 570, in _prefetch_related_objects
    prefetch_related_objects(self._result_cache, self._prefetch_related_lookups)
  File "/home/igor/workspace/projectname/eggs/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 1680, in prefetch_related_objects
    obj_list, additional_prl = prefetch_one_level(obj_list, prefetcher, attr)
  File "/home/igor/workspace/projectname/eggs/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 1803, in prefetch_one_level
    qs = getattr(obj, attname).all()
AttributeError: 'ModelB' object has no attribute 'event_object'
```

Comment: can you add the traceback of the `prefetch_related` error?

Comment: Why do you need a ModelC queryset? Can't you just make 2 different queries and treat them separately? I know my question is a little naive, but sometimes the problem is just how we face this difficulties

Comment: @marianobianchi no, we try to optimize some part of django admin, so we need a single queryset. Also the models above are simplified, we have deeper relations in real project

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug or oversight in django.  As a workaround, you can try defining a custom manager which does a 2-stage prefetching.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class PrefetchWorkaroundManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        q = super(PrefetchWorkaroundManager, self).get_queryset()
        content_typeA = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(ModelA)
        content_typeB = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(ModelB)
        return q.filter(content_type__pk = content_typeA.id).prefetch_related('content_object', 'content_object__event_object') | \
               q.filter(content_type__pk = content_typeB.id).prefetch_related('content_object', 'content_object__event')

class ModelC(models.Model):
    ...

    objects_prefetched = PrefetchWorkaroundManager()
```

Each caller which wants prefetching to take place should access `ModelC.objects_prefetched` instead of `ModelC.objects`:

```
ModelC.objects_prefetched.filter(...)
```

I admit, I didn't test it, so it probably doesn't work as-is.  But I believe this approach is sound.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it does not work. When you use `|` on querysets it builds a new queryset. And `prefetch_related` is evaluated when the queryset itself is evaluated. Also I'm not sure if it's bug in Django or not, but when you use `|` it uses prefetch lookups only from the first query